# How to execute a script before each angular compilation (esbuild)

Tags: angular

I'm using angular V17 with esbuild, and I have to execute a script (or a JS function) before each angular compilation(that means that if I use `ng watch`, the script should run every time a file is modified).

How can I implement this?

Comment: Check this: https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#on-start

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that case I think I should write it in the answer block and you close the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link to the official esbuild documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#on-start) where you find how to do it.